# Make background change in the same time as text does when hovering over

Tags: css

When hovering over the margin of the button, the background gets changed because of li:hover, but the text inside isn't, because the a:hover isn't triggered.

How can I fix this?

```css
html {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Livvic', sans-serif;
    background-color:#EEE2DC;
    color: #000;
}

#container-pagina {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#navigation-bar > ul {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#navigation-bar > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    color: #0269A4;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#navigation-bar > ul > li {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.875em 1.875em;
}

#navigation-bar > ul > li > a:hover {
    transition: color 0.4s;
    color: #fff;
}

#navigation-bar > ul > li:hover {
    transition: background-color 0.4s;
    background-color: #0269A4;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px)
{
    html {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Livvic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container-pagina"> <!--we need a container. id - fiindca e singur.-->
        <header>
            <div id="navigation-bar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li><!--
                    --><li><a href="">About</a></li><!--
                    --><li><a href="">Services</a></li><!--
                    --><li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>   
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I usually don't build menus this way, and I tried to do it like that. I would use a fixed width. But now I've tried doing it without a fixed width, and when doing it this way I don't know how to use the hover as I said.

Check the snippet. When you hover over the li, the a's color isn't changed and it won't be visible anymore.

How can I make the a color change too when the li is hovered over?

Comment: Change `li > a:hover` to `li:hover > a`

Comment: Add your reply as an answer. You were the first one to respond, so I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The selector `#navigation-bar > ul > li > a:hover` only activates when you are right above the `a` text. Instead, change it to `#navigation-bar > ul > li:hover > a`. This way, whenever you hover anywhere over the li box, it will also update the color of the `a` tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
#navigation-bar > ul > li:hover a{
    transition: color 0.4s;
    color: #fff;
}
```

This will change the color of a tag text when you hover on li